# psr-2 и phpStorm

Tags: php

есть перевод https://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/
есть то, что делает phpStorm

```
private
function example()
{
    foreach ()
    {
        foreach () {
            if () {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

почему private на отдельной строке
почему foreach имеют разный формат скобок?

что не так с этим кодом?

```
foreach ($t as $v) {
    $u = [];//unused local variable 'u'
    $u = str_split($v);
}
```

и ещё зубодробительно CodeFormatter:

```
AllmanStyleBraces
Before  
if ($a) {

}

After
if ($a)
{

}
```

вот полный код про "не используемую" переменную:

```
    $y = [];
    foreach ($t as $v) {
        $u = [];//unused local variable 'u'
        $u = str_split($v);

        $u = array_map([$this, 'array_map__myReplaceSumbols'], $u);

        $y[$v] = implode('', $u);
    }
    unset($v);

    $str = strtr($str, $y);//заменю на странице все комментарии на пробелы
```

Comment: первое - `Settings -> Editor -> Code&Style -> PHP -> Wrap after modifier list`

Comment: Что значит "что делает phpStorm". Что вообще происходило - вы ввели этот код или что?

Comment: "что не так с этик кодом", это вы про комментарий? или что? там написано черным по белому, что переменная не используется. смысла в ней нет.

Comment: по третьему смотрите всякие настройки braces, типа `Braces placemnet -> Other`, или там еще есть отдельно про `if`

Comment: @u_mulder речь видимо идет про автоформатирование кода

Comment: Всё настраивается в `Settings -> Editor -> Code&Style -> PHP`. Посидите потыкайте и тогда форматировать будет так, как вам надо. Что в третьем примере не так? Тоже связано с форматированием. Во втором примере написано, что переменная не используется

Comment: смотрите, второй пример и первый, if как по стандарту всё таки? открывающая скобка на то же строке? а foreach всегда где скобку ставить?

Comment: @teran я добавил полный код в вопрос, переменная используется, в этом и проблема

Comment: @u_mulder вопрос про разный стиль написания foreach - это результат форматирования текста phpStorm, почему по разному отформатировал?

Comment: @Василий "смотрите, второй пример и первый, if как по стандарту всё таки? открывающая скобка на то же строке? а foreach всегда где скобку ставить?" --- по какому именно стандарту? Есть PSR, а есть тот, что определён внутри компании, команды, проекта. Если PSR - то что-то может быть на новой, если своё соглашение - как определите

Comment: @Василий "phpStorm, почему по разному отформатировал?" - потому что в phpstorm  есть настройки, как просто для управляющих конструкций, так и для вложенных управляющих конструкций. Просто берёте и настраиваете всё под себя как вам нужно

Comment: @СергейМишин по PSR, вы вносите ещё больше путаницы https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: в общем подводя итог: есть стандарт PSR-12, есть дополнения по форматированию кода, которые нужно привести к стандарту, т.к. они коряво его поддерживают, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @Василий да, не успел исправить до коммента: PSR - что-то может быть на новой, у упр. конструкций - на той же строке

Comment: a = 2; a = 3; - первое значение естественно unused -  вы не использовали переменную до того, как присвоили ей значение

Comment: @splash58 я её объявил, когда-то любая переменная только появляется, я не могу понять логику

Comment: вы присвоили значение - пустой массив. Вас предупреждают, что это значение не использовалось. Я так понимаю этот комментарий

Comment: главное на null не ругается, в принципе задача обнулить значение, а т.к. не принципиально где присваивать тип переменной, можно использовать: $u = null; $u = [1,2,3,]; так получается?

Comment: у вас два присваивания `$u` подряд, логично что первое бесполезное. на него и ругается.