# стиль кодирования

Tags: php

как правильно организовать работу?
1. пишу как привык, потом скриптом поправить
2. пишу сразу по стандарту
3. пишу и ide сразу поправляет

Вопрос по последним двум пунктам: а если я не согласен например с заменой [] на array() или else if на elseif (что блт?)?

Как эти проблемы решаются в командной разработке?

Comment: > Как эти проблемы решаются в командной разработке? — Словами.

Comment: и настройкой IDE чтобы не поправляла, как не надо

Comment: Igor R. т.е. новая команда == новый стиль твоего кодирования?

Comment: Если не придерживаются стандартных правил zend, то да. Если придерживаются, то только в нюансах, которые не оговорены там + у каждой CMS/фреймворка есть свои специальные правила форматирования. 

Некоторые IDE можно на них настроить, например phpstorm умеет работать с правилами форматирования Wordpress и ряда других популярных CMS/фреймворков.

Comment: можно подумать, что прям так стили сильно отличаются.

Comment: Как в компании или команде определено - так и придется писать. Если не оговорено - оговорить все вместе и писать по соглашению. "как правильно организовать работу" --- определённого нет. лучше сразу писать по стандарту, чтобы проблем не огрести, потому что IDE не сможет всё поправить как надо. Как бы ты не  учитывал. Уже пройденный этап. А уж как привык тем более нельзя - это как музыканты будут ноты записывать кто как привык, или водители ездить кто как привык

Comment: Не уверен что вы будете это делать, однако неплохо было бы прочитать. Есть стандарты, которых в общем то не плохо было бы придерживаться. 

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Для гита есть инструмент, который проверяет стиль кодирования и запрещает пушить на сервер плохой код.

Comment: @zalex не уверен, что плевав на стандарты я бы в принципе задал этот вопрос. Читал, смотрел реализации, вопросов меньше не стало, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071106/psr-2-%d0%b8-phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

В PhpStorm прожми ctrl + alt + L для быстрого приведения кода в нормальный вид во всем файле.
А настроить то, к какому оформлению ide будет приводить твой код можно в настройках по пути:
**File** → **Settings** → **Editor** → **Code Style** → **PHP**

В командной разработке обычно просто договариваются, в каком стиле будет код.
Так же можешь почитать про стандарты оформлению кода psr-1 и psr-2
 [php-fig.org/psr/psr-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/)
[php-fig.org/psr/psr-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: psr2 устарел. Вместо него psr-12